# Kotlin, Inflated EditText, when keyboard shows, view is crumbled

Tags: java, android, kotlin

when keyboard is up, inflated view show weird.
what may be the problem ?

```
    val inflater = it.context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater?
    val menuPopup = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.popup_search_new_cosmetics,null)

    val popup = PopupWindow(menuPopup, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, true)
    popup.showAtLocation(menuPopup, Gravity.CENTER,0,0)
    val imgClose = menuPopup.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageClose)
    menuPopup.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageClose)
```

[image]

```
enter code here
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to describe what you consider to be wrong and / or what you expect how the view should be.

Comment: I couldn't understand your question properly, but I would like to ask is why you are using popup window instead of dialog or alert dialog?

Comment: I think the OP's talking about how the white background for that window becomes transparent in the second pic. I haven't used `PopupWindow` but yeah, I'd recommend using a dialog instead - those seem to work ok!